# Weaker than "weak" convergence of measures

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

I am reading this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures

and I'm wondering if there are some forms of convergence in measure that is weaker than "weak convergence" (aka weak* convergence) here. Or maybe just other forms of convergence of measure that don't imply this weak convergence. For example, I have heard of the Radon and Wasserstein metric and also the vague topology, but I believe (according to Wikipedia) each of these implies weak convergence.